# Mutt does not list all public keys

Tags: mutt, gpg

I am trying to use Mutt to send an encrypted message.  When I tell it to send, I am prompted "enter keyID for curly@there.com".  I hit enter and get a menu:

```
1 ?  2048/0x7F2D434B9741E8AC RSA  es
2 +  2048/0x5D7BF71DA8215631 RSA  es
3 +  2048/0x5D7BF71DA8215631 RSA  es Me <me@place.com>
4 ?  2048/0x8F2D434B9241E8AC RSA  es Moe <Moe@place.com>
```

Meanwhile if I use gpg -k I get

```
/home/Me/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
---------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2014-12-15 [C]
      EF6E286DDA75EA2A4BA7AE684E2C6E8713298290
uid           [ unknown] Larry (signing key) <larry@place.com>
sub   rsa4096 2014-12-15 [S]
sub   rsa4096 2014-12-15 [S]
sub   rsa4096 2014-12-15 [S]

pub   rsa2048 2016-06-06 [SC] [expires: 2017-03-02]
   A7EF81E08C076AA79B15041A5D7BBF71BD821562
uid           [ultimate] Me <me@place.com>
sub   rsa2048 2016-06-06 [E] [expires: 2017-03-02]

pub   rsa2048 2011-04-10 [SC]
      4AA4757CCC9C4B1D18AB28B77F2D432B9741E8AC
uid           [ unknown] Moe <moe@place.com>
sub   rsa2048 2011-04-10 [E]

pub   rsa4096 2014-09-06 [SC] [expires: 2019-08-05]
      8B641D862187FDE1E215C6B7CF62CAE28A17E01D
uid           [ unknown] Curly <curly@here.com>
uid           [ unknown] Curly <curly@there.com>
```

Any idea why Mutt is not finding all of my public keys?  <strike>For what it's worth, it is missing exactly the 4096-bit ones.</strike>  Nope, I addded a 4096-bit key that worked fine.

Finally, here is the output of mutt -v:

```
Mutt 1.7.1 (2016-10-04)
Copyright (C) 1996-2016 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 4.8.7-1-ARCH (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 6.0.20150808 (compiled with 6.0)
libidn: 1.33 (compiled with 1.33)
hcache backend: GDBM version 1.12. 16/05/2016 (built May 31 2016     18:36:34)

Compiler:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.1/lto-    wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --    libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man -    -infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.1 20160830 (GCC) 

Configure options: '--prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--enable-gpgme' '--enable-pop' '--enable-imap' '--enable-smtp' '--enable-hcache' '--enable-sidebar' '--with-curses=/usr' '--with-regex' '--with-gss=/usr' '--with-ssl=/usr' '--with-sasl' '--with-idn' 'CFLAGS=-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'

Compilation CFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -march=x86-64 -    mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong

Compile options:
-DOMAIN
-DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  -USE_SETGID  +USE_DOTLOCK  -DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK   
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_SMTP  
+USE_SSL_OPENSSL  -USE_SSL_GNUTLS  +USE_SASL  +USE_GSS      +HAVE_GETADDRINFO  
-HAVE_REGCOMP  +USE_GNU_REGEX  
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET  
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM  
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME      +CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME  
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT  
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET      +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR  
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_LIBIDN  +HAVE_GETSID      +USE_HCACHE  +USE_SIDEBAR  
-ISPELL
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/usr/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
-MIXMASTER
To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
To report a bug, please visit http://bugs.mutt.org/.
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys that Mutt lists are the encryption keys.  In this example I do not have a key for Curly that is usable for encryption (such a key would be marked with the "[E]" tag).